# Make Shape and Fill with Text

Tags: excel, vba

I want certain cells in the row I have selected (shown in B7) to link to a shape I have made on another sheet called "Board". Every time I click the Card_Trailer macro button I want a new shape made on the board sheet and for all of the below said cells from that row to show in the shape. If a change is made on the sheet, I want it to reflect on the shape as well.Sheet names: "Board" is sheet1 and "Trailers" is sheet2. SOS Help

```vb
Sub Card_Trailer () 

    With Sheet2 
        
         If MsgBox ("Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo, 
      "Proceed") = vbNo Then Exit Sub 
    
    
        Dim rw As Range
        Set rw = Sheet2.Rows(Sheet2.Range("B7").Value) 
    End With 
    
    Worksheets("Board").Activate
    Set newShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Card1").Duplicate 
    With newShape 
    
    
       .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = 
        Sheet2.Range("D1,E1,F1,H1,I1,K1,L1,M1,N1,O1" & rw).Value 
        .Shapes(newShape).Select 
    End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't put a bunch of cells into a shape as text like that - you will need to make a single string value from those cells and assign that. How should that look?

Comment: I just tried to reformat the code and screwed it up one second

Comment: is the new format above ok? or is that still wrong

Comment: You can assign a link via a shape's `Formula` property, but it seems it can only link to a single cell, so you will need a helper column on the Trailers sheet which has a formula joining the cells you want to display, and then link that cell to the copied shape on Board.

Comment: what does the helper column formula look like to combine these selected cells

Comment: `=D2 & ";" & E2 & ";" & F2 & ...` or however you want the content to appear in the shape.

Comment: ...or use `CONCATENATE()`

Comment: @TimWilliams can I hire you? I am looking for around 2-3 hours of help on this sheet. It may be less than that I dont know. If you are interested please respond with an email address so I can send a more detailed list of deliverables and you can give me a quote

Answer (score 0):

With a helper formula in ColZ (for example)

```vb
Dim wsCards As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, cd, r As Long

Set wsCards = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Board")
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trailers")
 
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo, "Proceed") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
r = wsData.Range("B7").Value
wsCards.Select

Set cd = wsCards.Shapes("Card1").Duplicate()
cd.Name = "Card_" & r 'otherwise it will be another "Card1"
cd.DrawingObject.Formula = "='" & wsData.Name & "'!Z" & r
```